# live search using ajax and jquery for divs

Tags: ajax

I am creating a live search with ajax php and mysql and i was wondering if it's possible to create a live search by a div name or rel, and when you finish writing on that page to remain only the divs you want?

Comment: So you have a page with a lot of divs and you want to show only the ones you are looking for in an input text (for example)?

Comment: Not sure of what you are asking. Live search on a div name or rel?

Comment: Without JavaScript? Though I'm not sure I know what you mean.

Comment: yes  i created an input text and while you type there the page will refresh using ajax and eventualy remain only the divs that have the name like your search

Comment: the problem is that i don't know how to target the div name instead of taking some data from mysql